# I need to subtract a base date from the current date plus 7 days; but not sure how to account for change in year?

Tags: python, selenium, datetime, selenium-chromedriver

```
PaymentDate = datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday + 7
NS_Date_Text = driver.find_element(By.ID, "custrecord_ps_inv_date_val").text
basedate = datetime.strptime(NS_Date_Text, '%m/%d/%Y')
basedate1 = datetime.timetuple(basedate).tm_yday
DaysUntilPayment = PaymentDate - basedate1
```

This code works so far for the year of 2019. But, I am not sure how to account for 2020 or 2018

So, I am converting the current date to the number of day in the year (January 1 would be 1 and December 31 would be 365/366) then adding 7 to that number. This is the **Payment Date**.

Then, I am finding a date on the webpage(**BaseDate**) and converting that number to the day of the year.

Then subtracting those two numbers.

I am not sure how well it's going to work if the current date is: January 10, 2020 (10th day) + 7 = day 17. But the base date is 12/28/2019 (362nd day).

The number I will get would be 345 and that's way too far ahead, while I need the number(**DaysUntilPayment**) to be 20.

I hope I was able to explain this well. Please lmk if you have any questions!

Comment: Don't. You have a `basedate` object, which is a `datetime.date()` object. Use a a `datetime.timedelta()` object to add or subtract from that, and it'll take care of all the details such as years and leap days.

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters! Could you give me an example of how that set up would look? I've known python for less than one month, so everything is still very new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making this way more complicated than it needs to be. Python's `datetime.date()` objects know how to handle deltas themselves; if you subtract two `date()` objects you get a [`timedelta()` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta), which has a `.days` attribute.

Next, you can create your own `timedelta()` object to add 7 days to 'today':

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

# 7 days from today
payment_date = date.today() + timedelta(days=7)

# find base date on the webpage
ns_date_text = driver.find_element(By.ID, "custrecord_ps_inv_date_val").text
basedate = datetime.strptime(ns_date_text, '%m/%d/%Y').date()

# calculate the difference in days between these two dates
# date - date = timedelta, so take the .days attribute from that result
days_until_payment = (payment_date - basedate).days
```

Note that I used *only the date component* of the `datetime.strptime()` result. You can do all this with `datetime` objects *too*, but then you may have to worry about timezones and such, and it's just easier not to have to do that.

These operations take care of details such as handling years, and more importantly, handling leap years:

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
>>> payment_date = date(2020, 2, 22) + timedelta(days=7)
>>> payment_date   # this is February 29th, a leap day!
datetime.date(2020, 2, 29)
>>> basedate = datetime.strptime("12/31/2019", '%m/%d/%Y').date  # last day of 2019
>>> payment_date - basedate
datetime.timedelta(days=60)
>>> (payment_date - basedate).days  # February 29th is 60 days later
60
```

For further details, see the [`datetime.date` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects), which has a *Supported operations* section, with:

> `date2 = date1 + timedelta`
>   `date2` is `timedelta.days` days removed from `date1`
>
> `timedelta = date1 - date2`
>   This is exact, and cannot overflow. `timedelta.seconds` and `timedelta.microseconds` are `0`, and `date2 + timedelta == date1` after.